# Write a program to print the sum of all the elements of an array of size N where N can be any integer between 1 and 100

Tags: python, arrays

Write a program to print the sum of all the elements of an array of size N where N can be any integer between 1 and 100. (1 \le N \le 100)

Instructions:

You have to take input variable N denoting the number of elements of the array.
Then you have to Input the elements of an array in a single line.
We have provided the code to get the input for the array elements.
You have to write the logic to add the array elements.
Print the sum.
Sample input
Sample output
3
1 2 3
6
Explanation of Sample I/O

N = 3
Array = 1 2 3

1 + 2 + 3 = 6

```
N = int(input())
nums = input()
# Get the input
numArray = map(int, input(),nums.split())

sum_integer = 0
# Write the logic to add these numbers here
for i in range(0,N):
    sum_integer = sum_integer[i]
# Print the sum
print (sum_integer)
```

Input:

```
3
1 2 3
```

Desired Output:
`6`

Actual Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 7, in <module>
    numArray = map(int, input(),nums.split())
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

what did i do wrong?
question from:
https://www.codingal.com/competitions/codewars-2021-all-problems/problems/4/

SOLVED:

```py
N = int(input())

numArray = list(map(int, input().split()))

sum_integer = sum(numArray)

print (sum_integer)
```

Comment: Remove `input(),` from your `map` call.  That's the first step.

Comment: done now what do i have to do

Comment: will this work?

Comment: Then you need `sum_integer += numArray[i]`,  What you have in the loop doesn't make sense.

Comment: Yes, your alternative will also work.

Comment: @TimRoberts still same error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 12, in <module>
    sum_integer += numArray[i]
TypeError: 'map' object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map` method takes two arguments **first** one is a `lambda` method for converting one data type to other data type and **second** is an `iterable` on with the first method operation will be performed.

before converting to `int` type using `filter` to remove the data like spaces

```
filter(lambda data:len(data.strip(), __iterables__)
```

After this operation calling `map(int, __iterables__)` which will convert data from `str` to `int` for all values in the `__iterables__` and `list(map(...))` converts the `map` to `list`.

```
N = int(input())
# Get the input
nums = input()
numArray = list(map(int,filter(lambda data:len(data.strip())>0,nums.split(' '))))
#print(numArray)

sum_integer = 0
# Write the logic to add these numbers here
for i in range(len(numArray)):
    sum_integer += numArray[i]
# Print the sum
print (sum_integer)
~
```

## Output:

```
$ python test.py
3
1 2 3
6
```

Or Something like this:

```
input()

print(sum( list(map(int, filter(lambda data:len(data.strip())>0, input().split(' '))))))
```

Comment: can you explain the map part?

Comment: Read it from inside out.  First, call `input` to read the input line, then split it into words.  Then we pass that to `filter`; the purpose of that is to get rid of any empty strings, if they should happen to have typed a space at the beginning (`"  1 2 3")`.  That leaves us with a list of strings.  We then pass that to `map`, which will call `int` on each string and return a set of integers, which we convert to a list, and pass to `sum`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this approach should work

```
arrlen = int(input());#length of the array
ele = [int(x) for x in input().split(' ')];
sumR = 0;
#This loop can be replaced by a simple sumR = sum(ele)
for i in range(arrlen):
     sumR+=ele[i];
print(sumR);
```